# Как вставить сюда свое местоположение

Tags: java, android

Есть код:

```
GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(55.895859, 37.719324, "hhh");
```

Как вместо локации вставить свое обновляющееся местоположение? Вот код GeoPoint:

```
package com.example.world_train;

import android.location.Location;

import java.util.Collection;

public class GeoPoint {

public final double lat;
public final double lon;
public String name;

public GeoPoint(double lat, double lon, String name) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public GeoPoint(Location location) {
    this.lat = location.getLatitude();
    this.lon = location.getLongitude();
}

public static GeoPoint getNearestLocation(GeoPoint current, Collection<GeoPoint> locations) {
    GeoPoint res = null;
    float lastDisance = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float locDistance[] = new float[1];
    for (GeoPoint loc: locations) {
        Location.distanceBetween(current.lat, current.lon,
                loc.lat, loc.lon, locDistance);
        if (res == null || locDistance[0] < lastDisance) {
            res = loc;
            lastDisance = locDistance[0];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот замечательный [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/291-urok-138-opredelenie-mestopolozhenija-gps-koordinaty.html). Если вы его хорошо разберете, то сможете без проблем сделать обновляемое местоположение.

Comment: Это немного не то.. Я сам это находил, но ничего дельного это особо не дало..

Comment: Обратите внимание на locationListener, в коде примера. Он как раз дает обновляющееся местоположение. Метод onLocationChanged вызывается когда местоположение меняется, осталось только получить из Location, координаты и подставить в GeoPoint. 
Попробуйте объяснить что вы хотите получить в итоге, какую задачу вы перед собой ставите?

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, сейчас поразбераюсь..